# Saving file in internal storage using Uri (obtained from Storage Access network)

Tags: android, kotlin, storage-access-framework

I'm using Storage Access Network to pick file and save in internal storage so that app can use if in future.

I'm getting URI without any issues. It's something like content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A141274

Problem comes when I'm trying to save image into internal directory. Code passes without crashes, image with same size is saved into internal directory (I can see it in device Explorer: https://take.ms/3TwBS).
But image itself is broken and can't be opened.

Here's code I'm using (after getting URI)

```
val destinationFile = File("${context.filesDir.absolutePath}/$fileName")
try {
                        val writer = FileWriter(destinationFile)
                        writer.append(readTextFromUri(it))
                        writer.flush()
                        writer.close()

                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()

                    }


 @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun readTextFromUri(uri: Uri): String {
        val inputStream = activity!!.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
        val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        var line: String? = null
        while ({ line = reader.readLine(); line }() != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line)
        }
        inputStream?.close()
        reader.close()
        return stringBuilder.toString()
    }
```

Comment: Your code is for reading and writing text. Your question implies that you are reading and writing images. Images are not text.

Comment: Correct, I already got to the point that content is broken during copying. So the right question is how to properly copy to File using InputStream.

Comment: Use the `copyTo()` extension function to copy the contents of an `InputStream` to an `OutputStream`: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-input-stream/copy-to.html

Answer (score 1):

As @CommonsWare described I should have used proper dealing with files, not texts.

Proper way to do:

```
private fun inputStreamToFile(uri: Uri){
        val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
        val output = FileOutputStream(File("${filesDir.absoluteFile}/magic.png"))
        inputStream?.copyTo(output, 4 * 1024)
}
```

Or longer way (without extension functions)

```
fun inputStreamToFile(uri: Uri){
        val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
        inputStream.use {
            val directory = getDir("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val file = File(directory, "correct.txt")
            val output = FileOutputStream(file)
            output.use {
                val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024) // or other buffer size
                var read: Int = inputStream?.read(buffer) ?: -1
                while (read != -1) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, read)
                    read = inputStream?.read(buffer) ?: -1
                }
                output.flush()
            }
        }
    }
```